# Getting Undefined offset: 0 php array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter, xmlhttprequest

I have the following array result returning from a table when called from xmlrpc client and want to send the this response to client side.

```
array(17) {
      ["A"]=>
      int(1)
      ["B"]=>
      int(0)
      ["pnl"]=>
      int(1)
      ["C"]=>
      int(1)
      
      ["buttons"]=>
      array(5) {
        [1]=>
        string(9) "ABC"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "DEF"
        [3]=>
        string(5) "G"
        [4]=>
        string(7) "H"
        [5]=>
        string(9) "I"
      }
      ["List"]=>
      string(580) "<th title="S">Ticker</th><th title="Position - Shares Held in Portfolio">Pos</th><th title="Average Cost">Cost</th><th title="Current Market Price">Price</th>"
    }
```

Currently using the following code to fetch the record but it returns undefined offsets .i got the above result using the var_dump function which contains all the data fetched . how can i change my loop to get the result in appropriate row?

> var_dump($model) ;
>
> ```
>         for ($i = 0; $i < count($model); ++$i) {
>             $xml_rpc_rows[$i] = array($model[$i], 'struct');
>         }
>        
>     }
>    $response = array(
>         $xml_rpc_rows,
>         'struct');
>     return $this->xmlrpc->send_response($response);
> ```

Comment: Try to loop with a `foreach`

Comment: please also note before entering `foreach()` check if desired `$variable` is fit for foreach or you'll get errors (in views mostly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop wants the following index from the array: `$xml_rpc_rows[$i]` which would translate to `$xml_rpc_rows[0]`, so index == 0. But your array has only indexes (keys) as: `$xml_rpc_rows['A']`.

The loop would also not work on the buttons array, since the first index for that array is 1. So your loop would need `$i=1`.

A foreach loop would give you more info and make it a bit clearer.

```
<?php
foreach ($model as $key => $val) {
  print $key . '<br />';
  print $val;
}
```

Now you can see the key / index your array uses and the values those contain.

Answer (score 1):

While creating your array you used letters as indexes but in your loop you're trying to use numerical indexes. Instead of that you should use `foreach` to iterate through this array.

Comment: $i=0;
              foreach ($model as $row):
                 
                  $xml_rpc_rows[$i]=$row;
                  $i++;
              endforeach;

Comment: but can i still pass it like this array($row[$i], 'struct');

Comment: ill just try it . i am having a different response set then i expected that is why i am asking . ill post the latest response

Comment: No, there is no index `$i` in `$row`.

Comment: yeah that line did cause offset issue again .. here is the response without ($row[$i] ,'struct')

Comment: the response is too long to be posted here .its probably some other issue foreach did solve my inital query so thankyou